# Object rending Blank on DOM and error when assigned to a global variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the object i am iterating through but getting error when i assign it to the global health variable.

This is my global variable

```
    public health: any;

    constructor(private forumservice: ForumService) {}


      ngOnInit() {
        this.forumservice.getHealths().subscribe(
          healths => {
            Object.keys(healths).forEach(function (key) {
              var topics = healths[key];
```

I am getting all the data i want till this point but when i pass the result to the global variable it giving error.

```
              this.health = topics.Topics;
```

Then i try to declare another variable here like const health but it wont render on the DOM just showing blank

```
            });
            console.log(this.health);
          },
          errmess => (this.errMess = errmess)
        );
```

Comment: Change from `function (key) {` to `(key) => {` otherwise the context of `this` is lost

Comment: @user184994 that's what i was gonna type! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Arrow functions** ES6 feature because it does not have its own `this` like classical **function expression**. So you need to rewrite your iteration like :

```
Object.keys(healths).forEach((key) => {
  ...
  this.health = topics.Topics;
  ...
}
```

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value (based on how function was called, a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the base object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an object-oriented style of programming.

More about **Arrow functions** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)